# grails databinding param a mapping on b

Tags: validation, grails, data-binding, nullable

in my current project, i was so stupid to make an API which expects the variable private. in the controller it gets mapped to isPrivate, but now i wanted to make a commandObject (@validatable) to check if everything is valid. How can i map the private variable using autobinding on isPrivate?

```
@Validateable
class EventCommand{
    boolean isPrivate
    boolean fullDay
    String title
    String location
    String description

    static constraints = {
        location(nullable: true)
        description(nullable: true)
        fullDay (nullable: false)
        isPrivate(nullable: false)
        title (blank: true, nullable: false)
    }
}
```

and the code where the databinding happens (inside a grails controllor):

```
def add() {
    def jsonData = request.JSON

    EventCommand command = new EventCommand(jsonData)
    if(!command.validate()){
        throw new QuivrException(command)
    }

    boolean isPrivate = jsonData.private
    //some things happen, uninmportant
}
```

i already tried using the @BindUsing annotation, but i always keep getting the error that EventCommand has no property named "private" (the matches works, but he tries to match private to something none-existant)

is there any way to solve this without changing the received private to isPrivated (already got old versions of the application and got 20% not on latest version)

Answer (score 0):

Well from your jsonData remove the private property and then do the binding and after binding add the private manually from  a variable in which you should be getting the private value.

Hence your add could be something like

```
def add() {
    def jsonData = request.JSON
    String isPrivate = jsonData.private
    jsonData.remove("private")
    EventCommand command = new EventCommand(jsonData)
    if(!command.validate()){
        throw new QuivrException(command)
    }

   command.isPrivate = isPrivate as Boolean
}
```

Comment: in this case i cannot check the existance of private in the command Object. Also when i add the isPrivate to the jsonData before making the command Object, i get not a binding error but a null exception when private is not given.